# Unable to open a folder that contains a . in finder

Tags: finder

I have a hand full of folders that contain the .service in the name.  When I attempt to open these folders in finder, it shows an icon that indicates that the file cannot be opened.

Is there a way to tell finder that these "files" are in fact folders so I can browse them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are still folders, just packaged. You can right-click the folder and choose Show Package Contents to show the contents of the package.

If you want to permanently set .service packages as not assigned to OS X so they're normal folders, you can remove item 257 from…

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
```

<sup>Note that editing this file incorrectly can break many things. Be careful and have backups.</sup>